# How to count every occurrence of a certain word in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, unique

Here are some examples of the entries in my dataframe in R.

- [1] "0"
- [2] "Warm"
- [3] "Touch"
- [4] "Tingling"
- [5] "Touch, Pressure"
- [6] "Pressure"
- [7] "Tingling,Other (describe)"
- Etc...

I want to count every occurrence of the following words: Pain, Tingling, Touch, Scratching, Other (describe), Pressure, Ticklish, Warm, Cold.

However, when I do
`sum(DF=="Touch")`
it only counts the cells where someone has only entered "Touch" but for example not "Touch,Pressure". How can I count every single cell where the word "Touch" occurs no matter whether it's together with another word? Any help would be much appreciated :), I just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to count for a substring word, then use `grepl` to look for the particular word pattern, by looping over the dataset with `lapply`, `Reduce` by doing an elementwise add (`+`) and take the `sum` of the vector

```
sum(Reduce(`+`, lapply(DF, grepl, pattern = "\\bTouch\\b")))
#[1] 5
```

Or it can be made compact, if we change the data to `matrix` with `as.matrix`

```
sum(grepl("\\bTouch\\b", as.matrix(DF)))
#[1] 5
```

NOTE: The `\\b` - specifies the word boundary in regex.  If we don't have those, then it could potentially match 'Touching', 'Touchy' along with 'Touch'

---

It can be wrapped in a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, word) {
         pat <- paste0("\\b", word, "\\b")
         count <- sum(Reduce(`+`, lapply(dat, grepl, pattern = pat)))
       return(count)
  }

f1(DF, "Touch")
#[1] 5
```

This can be also applied to multiple words

```
sapply(c("Warm", "Touch"), function(x) f1(DF, x))
# Warm Touch 
#    2     5
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(Col1 = c("0", "Warm", "Touch", "Tingling", 
     "Touch, Pressure", 
"Pressure"), Col2 = c("Touch", "Warm", "0", "Tingling", "Touch, Pressure", 
"Pressure, Touch")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```